# javascript element ":last" confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question about the interaction of the javascript code with the HTML code.

In this part of the lecture I'm working on, I'm to put in my work info into a .js file using a for-loop, which then interacts with other `.js` and `.html` file to output my job/role onto index.html and i did it like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < work.length; i++) {
    var role = HTMLworkTitle.replace("%data%",work[i].role);
    var employer = HTMLworkEmployer.replace("%data%",work[i].name);
    var description = HTMLworkDescription.replace("%data%",work[i].Description);
    var employerinfo = employer + role;
    $("#workExperience").append(HTMLworkStart);
    $(".work-entry:last").append(employerinfo);
}
```

The code works fine, but I'm trying to understand why we need ":last" in ".work-entry:last". The other file, helper.js only has one element entry for "work-entry" to begin with, shown below:

```
var HTMLworkStart = '<div class="work-entry"></div>';
var HTMLworkEmployer = '<a href="#">%data%';
var HTMLworkTitle = ' - %data%</a>';
```

So I tried taking out ":last" and the result started making random repetitions to the "employerinfo" output.

Comment: Can you show your html ?

Comment: I'm guessing `employerinfo` also contains a div with the class `work-entry`

Comment: Probably the code is looking for only 'one' match... So try using `:first` and see it it behaves the same. The documentation will be helpful for you, https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Answer (score 0):

[`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) is a jQuery specific meta-selector. Please see the example in the Documentation for clarification. What it does is select only the last element in the current selection. Since `work-entry` is a CSS-Class it hints, that there might be multiple DOM Elements assigned with this class. But your code seems to want to append the `employerinfo` only to the last `work-entry` on your page. I suppose the code is executed, after a new employer is added to your DOM. So if you wouldn't have `:last` it would append the current `employerinfo` to the already existing employers aswell instead of only the newly appended one.